# I am getting this error on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bluetooth, bluetoothadapter

This error has no relates to my web scraping bot at all. my code does not cause this error. it is just there, and I would like to get rid of it. any ideas?

`Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.`

Comment: I can't get extra info from your question. But I find the same error message [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/fxu2q3/suddenly_getting_odd_chromedriverselenium_errors/), hope can help you.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the logging when you initiate your driver:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-logging']);
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options);
```

I can't reproduce this to tell you if it will work however give it a go and let us know.
...Out of site, out of mind?